Arabic language (right to left) in pandas
Does pandas support the Arabic language?
rtl, examples :
بيانات الطلاب الجامعية :
اسم الطالب، رقم الطالب الجامعي، عنوان السكن، رقم الطالب، البريد الإلكتروني
I hope it will support the Arabic language soon.

What exactly do you mean by "support"?  If you just want to store or display this text, does the order of writing matter?
